# Lookup Table for BlackJack Deck of Cards

Tags: python, dictionary, lookup-tables, playing-cards, blackjack

I'm making a simple blackjack game that works perfectly -- until it comes to adding the face cards into the deck. This lookup table returns: KeyError: 1

I know (or at least am pretty sure) it's because of: 'rank': self.values[face]

Why does it return KeyError: 1  ? And how can this be fixed?

```
import random

class DeckOfCards(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.values = {"2": 2,
                   "3": 3,
                   "4": 4,
                   "5": 5,
                   "6": 6,
                   "7": 7,
                   "8": 8,
                   "9": 9,
                   "10": 10,
                   "J": 10,
                   "Q": 10,
                   "K": 10,
                   "A": 11,
                   }
    self.faces = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
    self.suits = ['C', 'D', 'H', 'S']
    self.unused_cards = []
    for suit in self.suits:
        for face in self.faces:
            self.unused_cards.append({'face': face, 'suit': suit, 'rank': self.values[face]})
    random.shuffle(self.unused_cards)
    self.used_cards = []

def play(self):
    print self.unused_cards

cardsss = DeckOfCards()
cardsss.play()
```

Comment: ...because `self.values` has no key `1`.

Comment: Just make sure, only keys of `values` are in `faces`: `self.faces = self.values.keys()`

Comment: Others have pointed out you mixing strings and integers. I'll also point out that your deck has 56 cards, because you have both 4 aces and 4 1s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this line, you are trying to access a key in the self.values dictionary that doesn't exist, because you have a self.face entry for '1' but you don't have a key in self.values for '1'.

```
self.unused_cards.append({'face': face, 'suit': suit, 'rank': self.values[face]})
```

Comment: Actually, that isn't a `SyntaxError` - lists, tuples, dicts etc. can all have a comma between the last item and the closing brace/bracket/parenthesis.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I guess you're right.  I don't use python often, and that's a syntax error in almost every other language I've ever used, so I guess I just assumed it is bad syntax in python too.  I should have checked it tho.  I remove that from the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `self.values` dict has strings as keys, but in `self.unused_cards.append({'face': face, 'suit': suit, 'rank': self.values[face]})` you are using a key of type `int`.

This will fix it:

`self.unused_cards.append({'face': face, 'suit': suit, 'rank': self.values[str(face)]})`

Answer (score 0):

you have inconsistency between `self.values` and `self.faces`.
In particular `self.values` has strings as keys while `self.faces` has some integers in it.

this is a possible fix:

```
self.faces = [ "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7","8", "9", "10", 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
```